# How to bake an air brick with all holes inside

Tags: modeling, texture-baking

how to bake an air brick

[image]

If i start with a cube i can have this result with a baked texture?

Comment: you won't be able to fake deep holes if that's your question, but you can fake the grooves on the sides

Comment: For the grooves how?

Comment: do you mean you don't know how to bake? You need to bake the normals, maybe follow a tutorial on this topic, if you meet an issue please tell

Comment: i try to bake with different method(normal, normal with cage). but dont bake the exactly map that i want. If i sent you the HP model con you try do this?

Comment: share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: this is the clean version : 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PEbnjo9E" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PEbnjo9E/)

Comment: I only see one object, where is the one that will receive the baking?

Comment: Add all items in the scene that you neeed: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=JLOos41j" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JLOos41j/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for solve my question.

1. create LQ object
2. Use magic UV map
3. bake AO of LP with HP
4. Clean result in inkscape
5. apply new texture to LQ object with Bump node.
   This is the result without subdivision.
   [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

It's because your grooves are made of faces that are completely parallel or frontal to the normals of the object that bakes, normal bake save only normals orientations, not depth, you need for example to give a small bevel to the angles or create b&w heights.

Comment: how to bake the heights correctly in my case(cube)?

Comment: it looks like it's now possible, perhaps check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1__olo3hds